# send a url with multiple querystring as a querystring parameter in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I need to send a redirect url as a query string parameter, 
unfortunately this url contains more than one querystring parameter as follows

> "http://host:port/page2.aspx?param1=value&param2=value&param3=value"

the problem is when I encode this url and send it via querystring , it looks as if it wasn't encoded , so my application consider the redirect url parameter value to be only

> "http://host:port/page2.aspx?param1=value"

and consider

> "&param2=value&param3=value"

as a part of the current url

I tried `Server.UrlEncode`
and `Server.HtmlEncode`

Comment: Could you show your code? The one you have tried with `Server.UrlEncode` and which didn't work?

Comment: it did Encode the url, but once it is redirected the encoding just disappear and the query string looks as if it was never encoded with all the '&' chars visible in the url in browser

if it might help you to know  the url is constructed in code behind and added to a link button PostBackUrl property when the grid is bound, since the link button is in a grid view rows

Comment: string url = string.Format("~/MyFolder/Page.aspx?Id={0}&RedirectUrl={1}", Id, Server.UrlEncode(MyRedirectUrl));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string myUrl = “http://host:port/page2.aspx?param1=value&param2=value&param3=value”;

string EncodedUrl = myUrl.EncodeTo64();
```

Pass this as querystring and retrieve using :

```
    EncodedUrl.DecodeFrom64();
```

Functions:

```
public static string EncodeTo64(this string target)
    {

        byte[] toEncodeAsBytes

              = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(target);

        string returnValue

              = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);

        return returnValue;

    }

public static string DecodeFrom64(this string target)
    {

        byte[] encodedDataAsBytes

            = System.Convert.FromBase64String(target);

        string returnValue =

           System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);

        return returnValue;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace '&' in your url with  '%26' or use Server.UrlEncode

```
Responsse.redirect("redirectURL?a='http://url2?a=5%26b=7'&b=9'");
 or
Responsse.redirect("redirectURL?a="+Server.UrlEncode("http://url2?a=5&b=7")+"&b=9'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode the URL

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string url)
```